# Iterating and modifying files in a directory

Tags: python, directory, edi, contextmanager

I already have code that works to modify one .edi file (testedifact.edi) in the same directory as my program.
however I need to run my script against a folder containing many of these .edi files so I basically want to use my code to be applied to every single file

here's what I have that works on one file:

```
segmentsNew = []
global segments     
with open( "testedifact.edi" , "r+") as edifactile:
    segments = edifactile.readlines()
    versionNumber = getVersionNumber(segments)
    for segment in segments:
        #do stuffs
edifactile.close()
with open ("testedifact.edi" , "w") as edifactfile:
    edifactile.writelines(segmentsNew)
edifactfile.close()
```

but I want to be able to do this for files outside of this directory and also on our network drives..

I've tried iterating through the files in my directory (as a little test) and passing every file to "`with open..`" like this

```
directory = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\name\test_edi_dir')
for file in directory:
    print("printing file names:", file)
    with  open(file, 'r') as edifactfile:
        pass

print(edifactfile.closed)
```

and I keep getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testedifact - Kopie (10).edi'` though it prints the file name.. what am I doing wrong?

could someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` only contains the file-name, not the path it is stored in. You need to pass this, too.

```
path = r'C:\Users\name\test_edi_dir/'
directory = os.listdir(path)

for file in directory:
    print("printing file names:", file)
    with open(path+file, 'r') as edifactile:
        pass
```

Comment: thanks for the help, though now I get `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\name\\test_edi_dirtestedifact - Kopie (10).edi'` .. why is it combining the directory name with my file name? i tried adding a space but i cant get it to separate them.. any ideas?

Comment: There is a missing `/` at the end of your path (which is present in my piece of code).

Answer (score 1):

That happens because when you call `open(file, 'r')` it tries to open a file in the current working directory.

Change your code to this:

```py
directory = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\name\test_edi_dir')
for file in directory:
    print("printing file names:", file)
    with  open('C:\Users\name\test_edi_dir\' + file, 'r') as edifactile:
        pass

    print(edifactfile.closed)
```

The next issue is that some *files* will be actually a *directories*, and your code may fail with the following error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '...'
```

So you want to check if file is actually a file, before opening it:

```py
isFile = os.path.isfile('C:\Users\name\test_edi_dir\' + file)
```

And finally a complete code is:

```py
directory = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\name\test_edi_dir')
for file in directory:
    print("printing file names:", file)
    full_filename = 'C:\Users\name\test_edi_dir\' + file
    if os.path.isdir(full_filename):
         continue
    with  open(full_filename, 'r') as edifactile:
        pass

    print(edifactfile.closed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to pass the entire image path:

```
with open('C:\Users\name\test_edi_dir\' + file, 'r') as edifactile:
    pass
```